# Toshiba laptop with Windows 7 is inexplicably slow?

Tags: windows-7, performance, toshiba-laptop

I have a 3 month old Toshiba Satellite laptop with 4GB RAM, i5 processor and a normal HDD (not SSD).

I dual boot with Ubuntu and I use Windows sparingly. However, I noticed that it is painstakingly slow on startup. I have Avast anti-virus installed so viruses shouldn't be a problem.

I suspect it is one of the Toshiba Software which is causing the slowness. There are quite a few and I'm not sure what to try to disable.

Any Toshiba users have a clue what is the resource hog here?

Comment: Give [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/) a try. I quote [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2011UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx): "It analyses all the things that happen during your system's boot and rearranges, delays, defers and speeds up your boot by analyzing what worked for everyone else using the tool." [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) is another good tool.

Comment: You could also try CCleaner to get rid of all the debris on the system first http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure you have gotten rid of any 'bloatware' that came pre-installed on your laptop. Almost all of the pre-installed software is unnecessary. Just go through add/remove programs and get rid of anything unnecessary.

You can also use [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to check what is getting started at boot. Untick anything you don't want to start.

Comment: Alternatively or aswell use PC Decrapifier for bloatware removal http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how confident you are, but, you can type msconfig in the run (or press the <kbd>[image]</kbd> and then <kbd>r</kbd>) and select what you want in the start up tab.

Comment: I tried that but as I said in my question I'm not sure which ones to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the service Superfetch running and next try to speed up the boot with the help of [my guide](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140262). This trains the advanced prefetcher in Windows 7. This increase the boot performance a lot. All other tweaking tools are useless. Only use this method with this Microsoft Toolkit.

If this doesn't speed up the boot process, [follow my guide to make a boot trace](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247) and compress the **boot_BASE+CSWITCH+DRIVERS+POWER_1.etl** as 7z or RAR and upload it. I take a look at the trace, maybe I see what's wrong with your Windows.